# How to truncate each line in a multiline textview

Tags: textview, truncate, multiline

I have a multiline textview (4 lines) which I populate with 4 strings and use the \n character to introduce the next line
ie.

```
TextView.setText(string1+"\n"+string2+"\n"string3+"\n"string4);
```

However, if one of the strings is longer that the textview width, it goes to the next line.  This means that the last string does not get shown since an earlier string took up 2 lines.  I'd like to truncate each line of the multiline textview to ensure that each string is shown.  Currently only the last line is truncated.

eg.

```
String 1 = "Jeff"
     String 2 = "24 years old"
     String 3 = "male"
     String 4 = "blond"
```

Would like TextView to read

```
Jeff 
24 year...
male
blond
```

But instead it reads

```
Jeff
24 years
old
male
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to use the method:

```
stringByTruncatingStringWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

To build each line of the string separately and concatenating the results. And then assign the result to the text property of the multiline label.

See:
[How to truncate an NSString based on the graphical width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266396/how-to-truncate-an-nsstring-based-on-the-graphical-width)
for this method.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the scrollHorizontally="true" property to true...hope it helps